# Efficient way to Reshape Huge Data in R

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, reshape

I have a huge data in `R` that I am trying to reshape it in an efficient way. As you see, the changes happen in column `Med` and `Num`. BTW, I have already tried to find a rigid answer but I was not successful.

Any idea would be great!

Thanks.

**Original shape:**

```
User    Date    Sex    Age  Ethic   Med    Num  Diag   Dis  Doc   Month
27168   1/1/2002    1   49  NULL    42506   1   2000    0   13545   1
27168   1/1/2002    1   49  NULL    32603   9   2000    0   13545   1
27168   1/1/2002    1   49  NULL    32602   5   2000    0   13545   1
27168   1/1/2002    1   49  NULL    34533   1   2000    0   13545   1
12335   2/1/2002    0   87  2       42506   2   8654    2   34568   1
12335   2/1/2002    0   87  2       65873   4   8654    2   34568   1
```

**Desired Shape:**

```
User    Date   Sex  Age Ethic  42506  32603  32602  34533  65873  Diag  Dis  Doc  Month
27168 1/1/2002  1   49  NULL     1      9      5      1      0    2000   0  13545   1
12335 2/1/2002  0   87   2       2      0      0      0      4    8654   2  34568   1
```

Comment: By "Huge data" what do you mean? Can you provide more info on the context?

Answer (score 2):

```
df %>%
   pivot_wider(names_from = Med, values_from = Num, values_fill = 0)

# A tibble: 2 x 14
   User Date       Sex   Age Ethic  Diag   Dis   Doc Month `42506` `32603` `32602` `34533` `65873`
  <int> <chr>    <int> <int> <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>
1 27168 1/1/2002     1    49 NULL   2000     0 13545     1       1       9       5       1       0
2 12335 2/1/2002     0    87 2      8654     2 34568     1       2       0       0       0       4
```

Comment: Thank you @onyambu for the answer. I get the following error. What it could be about?    Error: Can't convert <double> to <list>.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
In addition: Warning message:
Values are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.
* Use `values_fn = list` to suppress this warning.
* Use `values_fn = length` to identify where the duplicates arise
* Use `values_fn = {summary_fun}` to summarise duplicates

Comment: @EsterSilva you have duplicate keys. probably include `values_fn = list`

Comment: Now it got much better but still get the following error: "Can't convert <double> to <list>"